# Maven wrapper plugin throws error trying to update itself

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I've previously used the takari maven wrapper. Always worked (and still does).

```
mvnw -N io.takari:maven:wrapper -Dmaven=3.9.5
```

I happened to notice yesterday that this has long been deprecated and Apache built this into maven.

```
mvnw wrapper:wrapper -Dmaven=3.9.5
```

This results in:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-wrapper-plugin:3.2.0:wrapper (default-cli) on project demo: xxx\demo\demo\.mvn\wrapper\maven-wrapper.jar: The process cannot access the file beca
use it is being used by another process -> [Help 1]
[
```

The original Takari version could update itself. What's the point of the built in Apache version if it can't do that? You'd need to use an external maven for that or update the properties by hand.

Comment: Have you opened your project in your IDE on windows? Close the project in your IDE because some IDE's accessing the wrapper...

Comment: @khmarbaise I've tried the Apache one from the IntelliJ terminal window as well as completely closing IntelliJ and doing it from the command prompt. Same error. The Takari one could update itself from everywhere. Seems like its the plugin trying to update the jar file whereas I think the Takari one just updated the properties file.

Comment: Also the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/wrapper/) states that the update should be done via `mvn wrapper:wrapper -Dmaven=3.9.5` and not `./mvnw...` retry via `mvn...`...Because the `mvnw` is the wrapper itself ;-)

Comment: @khmarbaise Yeah, that would mean you need an external maven as well, which kind of defeats the point :). The Takari plugin works correctly.  But looks like the Apache one is failing here: https://github.com/apache/maven-wrapper/blob/master/maven-wrapper-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/wrapper/WrapperMojo.java#L203
It tries to delete itself. Oh well... guess I'll stick to the Takari wrapper since that works as expected.

Comment: @SledgeHammer this would work under Linux.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm using Windows for the context of this post.

Comment: @SledgeHammer this is why you have the problem.  Don’t blame the library for your choice of operating system.

Comment: If you have run the wrapper once you have installed a Maven in your local cache...

Comment: So I need to add .\xxx\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.9.5-bin\32db9c34\apache-maven-3.9.5\bin to my path? lol.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen why not? everything else works on Windows.

Comment: No you can call it simply once... if you really need...for the update...that's it.

Comment: @khmarbaise No, you'd need to call the external mvn whenever you want to update the maven version (or update the properties by hand as I mentioned).

Comment: The other question is how often do you need to do that ? I install Maven only directly (single version on my machine) and don't use the wrapper because there is no issue related to Maven updates? So committing a wrapper etc. in my git repos it not worth... (I have a large number of repos hundrets..)

Comment: I update the Maven wrapper whenever there is a new Maven version (yes, it is not that often). Committing the wrapper to git is the whole point :). Anybody should be able to pull down a repo and build and run it without touching a single thing. At least that's my MO :). I try keep everything (including dependencies) up to date. Otherwise, you've never tried to update a project that has 2-3 yr old dependencies :).

Comment: Guess I'll stick to the Takari one since it works on Windows.